# Recursive binary search for a string - C++

Tags: c++, recursion, binary-search

I am trying to implement the function `findMatchesInDict` that trys to see if a word matches any word in a pre-sorted dictionary. Below is my current implementation:

```
void findMatchesInDict(string word, int start, const string dict[], int end, string results[], int& totalResults)
{
    // initial start = 0 index
    // initial end = last index of dict array

    int middle = start + (end - start) / 2;
    if (end < start)
        return;

    if (word == dict[middle]) // if we found a match
        storeUniqueMatches(word, 0, results, totalResults); 
    else if (word < dict[middle])
        findMatchesInDict(word, start, dict, middle - 1, results, totalResults);
    else
        findMatchesInDict(word, middle + 1, dict, end, results, totalResults);
}
```

The `storeUniqueMatches` function works properly (this just stores a matching word into the `results` array ensuring no duplicate words are stored.

The function will only match select words from the dictionary but not others.

Any ideas as to why this may not be working properly?

---

For reference, this implementation works, but is horribly inefficient and causes stack overflow errors.

```
void findMatchesInDict(string word, int start, const string dict[], int end, string results[], int& totalResults)
{
    if (start > end) 
        return;
    if (word == dict[start]) // if we found a match
        storeUniqueMatches(word, 0, results, totalResults);

    findMatchesInDict(word, start + 1, dict, size, results, totalResults);
}
```

Comment: @FeiXiang just edited to add this. It won't match certain words, but does work for others. My other algorihtm works for all words in dict.

Comment: Try using a debugger. Do you mean that if you give it certain words, the algorithm doesn't find the word? Are you sure the array is sorted lexicographically? Try making a [mcve] which we can use to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Binary search which works for some values but not for others - sounds familiar. From my experience, the algorithm may have errors or better inaccuracies i.e. some border cases are not handled correctly, off by 1 mistakes, or something like this. I would try to find a non-working example for a not too big dictionary size and then debug this step by step to see where it goes wrong. For your luck, even for 1000 dict. entries, binary search should terminate after 10 recursions - the power of **ld** (logarithm dualis), you know? ;-)

Comment: Btw. did you ensure correct sorting? Did you ensure that sorting provides the exact same order as assumed in binary search? Yet another experience of mine: it's hard to find errors in code if you search at the wrong lines... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I still believe the OP did an off by 1 error.

I strongly suspect that

```
findMatchesInDict(word, start, dict, middle - 1, results, totalResults);
```

should be

```
findMatchesInDict(word, start, dict, middle, results, totalResults);
```

I made my own little sample. (Thereby, I re-designed the code a little bit as I felt unlucky about how the OP did.)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

size_t find(const std::string &word, const std::string dict[], size_t i0, size_t size)
{
  if (!size) return (size_t)-1; // bail out with invalid index
  const size_t i = i0 + size / 2;
  return word == dict[i]
    ? i
    : word < dict[i]
      ? find(word, dict, i0, i - i0)
      : find(word, dict, i + 1, i0 + size - (i + 1));
}

int main()
{
  const std::string dict[] = {
    "Ada", "BASIC", "C", "C++",
    "D", "Haskell", "INTERCAL", "Modula2",
    "Oberon", "Pascal", "Scala", "Scratch",
    "Vala"
  };
  const size_t sizeDict = sizeof dict / sizeof *dict;
  unsigned nErrors = 0;
  // brute force tests to find something what is in
  for (size_t n = 1; n <= sizeDict; ++n) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      if (find(dict[i], dict, 0, n) >= n) {
        std::cerr << "ALERT! Unable to find entry " << i << " in " << n << " entries!\n";
        ++nErrors;
      }
    }
  }
  // brute force tests to find something what is not in
  for (size_t n = 1; n <= sizeDict; ++n) {
    if (find("", dict, 0, n) < n) {
      std::cerr << "ALERT! Able to find entry '' in " << n << " entries!\n";
      ++nErrors;
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
      if (find(dict[i] + " + Assembler", dict, 0, n) < n) {
        std::cerr << "ALERT! Able to find entry '" << dict[i] << " + Assembler' in " << n << " entries!\n";
        ++nErrors;
      }
    }
  }
  // report
  if (!nErrors) std::cout << "All tests passed OK.\n";
  else std::cerr << nErrors << " tests failed!\n";
  // done
  return nErrors > 0;
}
```

<kbd>[**Live Demo on coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58dd0535a3baaaf7)</kbd>

The most of this code is brute-force test code:

1. Every length from 1 to size of `dict` is tested. For each length, any entry of `dict` is searched.
2. Every length from 1 to size of `dict` is tested. For each length, the empty string is tested (before any other entry) as well as any entry with a modification. (The modification grants that it would be between unmodified entry and its successor or after any entry for the last.)

Output:

```
All tests passed OK.
```

Everything went well.

Then I replaced

```
find(word, dict, i0, i - i0)
```

with

```
find(word, dict, i0, i - i0 > 0 ? i - i0 - 1 : 0)
```

to resemble what is (in my feeling) wrong with OP's code.

Output:

```
ALERT! Unable to find entry 0 in 2 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 0 in 3 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 1 in 4 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 1 in 5 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 3 in 5 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 0 in 6 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 2 in 6 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 4 in 6 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 0 in 7 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 2 in 7 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 4 in 7 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 0 in 8 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 3 in 8 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 5 in 8 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 0 in 9 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 3 in 9 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 6 in 9 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 1 in 10 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 4 in 10 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 7 in 10 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 1 in 11 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 4 in 11 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 7 in 11 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 9 in 11 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 1 in 12 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 3 in 12 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 5 in 12 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 8 in 12 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 10 in 12 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 1 in 13 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 3 in 13 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 5 in 13 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 7 in 13 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 9 in 13 entries!
ALERT! Unable to find entry 11 in 13 entries!
35 tests failed!
```

Well. Actually, this doesn't prove anything concerning the code of OP.

However, this shows

1. that "off by 1" can break binary search essentially.
2. how a brute force test can be designed to uncover such errors.

So, this will hopefully help the OP to find the error in his algorithm on his own (which is actually even more valuable for him).